# QGuiApplication::commitDataRequest: QML window is not painted

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to add quit confirmation message at OS shutdown according to this example:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsessionmanager.html#allowsInteraction

I interact with the user via QML interface. It is asynchronous, so I use slots/signals. And I use additional QEventLoop to stay inside of QGuiApplication::commitDataRequest call while interacting with the user.

The trouble is that after I shutdown OS (Windows 10) - my app prevents OS to shutdown and it's good, but its screen is just white, or contains old state without the confirmation dialog. I need to hide/restore window or change its size, or do some mouse clicks inside of it to force it repaint. When it repaint all is OK and my confirmation dialog is there.

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

This is the code I use:

```
void AppQuitConfirmationAtOsShutdownManager::onCommitDataRequest(
        QSessionManager &m)

{   
    if (!m_ui->isConfirmationRequired())
        return;

    if (!m.allowsInteraction())
        return;

    bool isConfirmed = true;

    QEventLoop loop;

    qtconnect(m_ui.data(), &AppQuitConfirmationUiManager::confirmationResult,
              &loop, [&](bool confirmed)
    {
        isConfirmed = confirmed;
        loop.quit();
    },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);

    m_ui->requestConfirmation();

    loop.exec();

    m.release();

    if (!isConfirmed)
        m.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I've never been fond of nested event loops. They are a bad idea. Always prefer async. QML has JS Promise support that makes this very easy. Hopefully QML will get "await" soon.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  I don't like nested event loops too, but I have to use them in this case. If you know how to avoid this - please let me know. The only way I know about is to just use QMessageBox instead of QML.

Comment: Have you tried manually breaking in a debugger after the problem appeared? Is execution really in the loop you want it to be in? Is it running or stuck on something? Try compiling in "Debug" mode and install Qt source code to get a better stack trace. You can also try to configure debugging symbol server and debug with a Microsoft debugger - although I'm not sure if that would work or can help you. If you can't make sense of the debugger, try putting log trace messages everywhere to try to detemine where you are stuck. Verify that the main GUI thread was not just terminated by something.